# Как рассчитать размер FAT32?

Tags: fat32

Объём жёсткого диска 128гб, а размер блока - 32Кб. Как из этих данных получить размер FAT32, а так же количество блоков на диске, и посчитать размер записи в FAT 32 (в байтах), обеспечивающую адресацию всех блоков?

Я пробовала объём жёсткого диска в Кб поделить на размер блока, но не уверена, что это является корректным решением.

Comment: "получить размер FAT32" - имеется ввиду количество места, которое можно занять файлами, то есть 128 Гб минус объем служебной информации?

Answer (score 2):

128 Гб диск = 128 * 1024 * 1024 = 134217728 кб диск

134217728 кб диск / 32 кб блок = 4194304 блоков

FAT32 - 32 бита = 4 байт на блок

4194304 блоков * 4 байта = 16777216 байт на одну копию FAT

16777216 байт / 512 байт в секторе = 32768 секторов на одну копию FAT, 65536 секторов на обе копии.

Всё это - без учёта расходов на таблицу разделов и резервированные/неиспользуемые секторы между разделами, служебные разделы и служебные структуры раздела, по которому выполняется подсчёт.

Comment: А где эти все формулы найти?

Comment: Какие именно формулы? перевод гектаров в килограммы? битов в байты? расчёт количества кусков в целом?